# Can I use babel with firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to use es6 with firebase functions?

There are some es6 classes that I need to import from my react native app into firebase functions.

Any pointers on how to do this will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions uses the LTS channel of Node.js, so a good chunk of ES6 syntax is supported out of the box and you could certainly use babel to compile down.